# What are the odds of two people being randomly seated next to each other in a stadium with 41, 798 seats?

Tags: probability

What are the odds of two people being randomly seated next to each other in a stadium with 41, 798 seats?

Not sure if it is just 2 in 41,798 or if there is a more complicated (and precise) way of calculating this

Thank you!

Comment: How many rows in the stadium?

Comment: There are 76 rows - thanks!

Comment: So long as there are at least three seats per row and no “end” seats, it doesn’t matter how many rows there are. Every seat has two neighbors, so the probability is 2 in 41,797. (Not 41,798, because once the first person is seated, the second person must be seated somewhere else.)

Comment: Thanks, Steve - there are end seats. I think 20 per row. If you assume that, how do you calculate the odds? (And thank you for the correction on the total number being minus the first person. Obvious now, but I missed it) :)

Comment: Welcome to MathSE! You are more likely to get a good answer to your question if you follow [a few guidelines](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).  In particular, give all the needed context for the problem. Does every seat have exactly two neighbors? (A seat by the aisle would probably be counted as having only one neighbor). How many seats have only one neighbor?

Comment: Thanks so much, Rory - I'm new to the site, and hopeless at math as you can probably tell :)

I'm creating a gift for my fiance which calculates the odds of us having met, which we did by being seated next to each other randomly at a sporting match in a stadium with 41,798 seats (Once calculated, I will have it framed with the tickets from that day which we both still have).  

I wasn't sure how to even approach the problem, but now that I know rows and "end seats" are important, I will estimate 20 ends seats x 76 rows, so 1520 neighbourless seats I would say for the purposes of the question

Answer (score 0):

The prob of the first person sitting in an end-seat is 1520/41798. In that case the prob of the second person sitting next to them is 1/41797. The prob the first person is not in an end seat is 40278/41798. The prob of the second person sitting next to them is 2/41797. So the total prob is 41038/873515503 or roughly 1 in 21286.